# iterated harmonic numbers vs Riemann zeta

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Define the *$m$-th iterated harmonic sums* in the manner: $\bar{H}_0(n):=1$ and for 
$m\geq1$ by
$$\bar{H}_m(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\bar{H}_{m-1}(k)}k.$$ 
For example, $\bar{H}_1(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ are the familiar harmonic numbers. Euler proved that
$$\frac12\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\bar{H}_1(n)}{n^2}=\zeta(3).$$

Hoping for a natural generalization, I ask:

> **Question 1.** Is this true? If so, any proof?
>   $$\frac1{m+1}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\bar{H}_m(n)}{n^2}=\zeta(m+2).$$

Of course, this works for $m=0$ as well: $\frac1{0+1}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\bar{H}_0(n)}{n^2}=\zeta(2)$.

> **Question 2.** This might be of auxiliary interest. Any proof?
>   $$\bar{H}_m(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^m}\binom{n}k.$$

Comment: how far did you check it numerically?

Comment: Quite extensively.

Comment: If true, it would be a really beautiful formula.

Comment: This infinite sum can be expressed in terms of multiple zeta values. In the case $m=2$ we have $\sum_{n \geq 1} H_2(n)/n^2 = \zeta(2,1,1)+\zeta(3,1)+\zeta(4)+\zeta(2,2) = \zeta(4)+(1/4)\zeta(4)+\zeta(4)+(3/4)\zeta(4)=3\zeta(4)$ as you predicted (these relations date back essentially to Euler).

Comment: Regarding Question 2, I am quite certain the identity is a special case of an identity of Hoffman and Kawashima. See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702824 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401319

Comment: Can you give reference pages?

Comment: @Lewi_Sol: See Theorem 4.2 in Hoffman's paper and Theorem 3.8 in Kawashima's paper. I am lazy to check all the details (how the identity in Question 2 follows from these).

Comment: You may be right, but it seems obscure to me.

Comment: @Lewi_Sol: I think the identities recorded in these papers are not obscure but very general.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answer to **Question 1.**

Define the multi-zeta value $\zeta(p_1,\ldots, p_g)$ as follows: 
$$ 
\zeta(p_1,\ldots,p_g) = \sum_{a_1>a_2 >\ldots > a_g\ge 1}\frac{1}{a_1^{p_1}\cdots a_g^{p_g}},
$$ 
where $p_1\ge 2$ and the other $p_j$ are integers $\ge 1$.  [Granville](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Riemann.pdf) and Zagier independently showed that 
$$ 
\sum_{p_1+\ldots+p_g= N} \zeta(p_1,\ldots,p_g) = \zeta(N), 
$$ 
where in the sum  $g$ is fixed, and the sum is over all tuples with $p_1\ge 2$ and other $p_j \ge 1$.  This generalizes Euler's relation 
$$
\zeta(2,1)=\zeta(3).
$$ 
Your result follows from this, upon distinguishing in your harmonic sum 
when some terms can equal others. For example consider your $m=2$ case 
which is 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m_1\le n} \frac{1}{m_1} \sum_{m_2\le m_1}\frac{1}{m_2} =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{m_2 \le n} \frac{1}{m_2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m_1 <n} \frac{1}{m_1} \sum_{m_2 \le m_1} \frac{1}{m_2} 
$$
and the first term is 
$$ 
\zeta(4)+\zeta(3,1),
$$
while the second term is 
$$ 
\zeta(2,2)+\zeta(2,1,1).
$$
These add up to $3\zeta(4)$ by Granville-Zagier.

Comment: Nice proof. Actually, the OP's left hand side is the multiple zeta star value $\zeta^\ast(2,1_m)$, so chances are that his identity is already in the literature.

Comment: Lucia: great reference. Compiling all the places wherever equality occurs (such as your examples, $\zeta(2,2), \zeta(2,1,1),$ etc requires additional justification, especially in higher dimensions. What do you do there?

Comment: @Lewi_Sol: In expanding out the harmonic sums, all that matters is how many of them are distinct.  Since there are $m+1$ terms (including $n$) this gives $m+1$ possible combinations.

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan:  I don't mind your edit, but when I answered the question, there was only Question 1!

Comment: @Lewi_Sol: (continuing Lucia's comment) ... and each combination contributes $\zeta(m+2)$.

Comment: I appreciate this.

Comment: @Lucia: I know. Not to worry. You get a cool bonus in the end. :-)

Comment: See also my response.

Answer (score 10):

The identity in Question 1 is a special case of Theorem 2 in Ohno: A Generalization of the Duality and Sum Formulas on the Multiple Zeta Values (see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X98923149)). Indeed, putting $k=1$ and $n=m+1$ in this theorem, and noting that $\xi_1(s)$ equals $s\zeta(s+1)$, the result follows.

Comment: That's a nice generalization.  Minor comment: I guess in the last line you want $\xi_1(s)$ in Ohno's notation.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I messed up the notation, it seems that Note 5.3 of this paper

> Luis A. Medina, Victor H. Moll, and Eric S. Rowland, *Iterated primitives of logarithmic powers*, International Journal of Number Theory **7** (2011) pp 623–634, doi:[10.1142/S179304211100423X](https://doi.org/10.1142/S179304211100423X), arXiv:[0911.1325](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1325) ([pdf](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/papers_html/itlog-final.pdf))

answers **Question 2**.

It seems quite likely that the OP is well aware of the above paper, given this recent paper:

> Tewodros Amdeberhan, Christoph Koutschan, Victor H. Moll, Eric S. Rowland, *The iterated integrals of $\ln(1 + x^n)$*, International Journal of Number Theory **8** (2012) pp 71–94  doi:[10.1142/S1793042112500042](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793042112500042), arXiv:[1012.3429](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3429) ([.ps file](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~erowland/papers/The_iterated_integrals_of_ln(1+x%5En).ps)).